# Assign Repeated Statement to a Variable

Tags: mysql

Below is the working stored procedure.  How can I assign the repeated code under the case statement to a variable and use it so I can reduce the number of coding lines?  The purpose of the procedure is to update the table with start_date and end_date for each CASE statement.  Thank you for your help and advise.

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE period x
    SET start_date = CASE 
        when return_period = 'L3M' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -2 Month))
        when return_period = 'YTD' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL 1-MONTH((select max(monthend_date) from returns y 
            WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id)) Month))
        when return_period = '1YR_CUM' or return_period = '1YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -11 Month))
        when return_period = '2YR_CUM' or return_period = '2YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from eturns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -23 Month))
        when return_period = '3YR_CUM' or return_period = '3YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -35 Month))
        when return_period = '4YR_CUM' or return_period = '4YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -47 Month))
        when return_period = '5YR_CUM' or return_period = '5YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -59 Month))
        when return_period = '6YR_CUM' or return_period = '6YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -71 Month))
        when return_period = '7YR_CUM' or return_period = '7YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -83 Month))
        when return_period = '8YR_CUM' or return_period = '8YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -95 Month))
        when return_period = '9YR_CUM' or return_period = '9YR_ANN' then             
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -107 Month))
        when return_period = '10YR_CUM' or return_period = '10YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -119 Month))
        when return_period = '11YR_CUM' or return_period = '11YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -131 Month))
        when return_period = '12YR_CUM' or return_period = '12YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -143 Month))
        when return_period = '13YR_CUM' or return_period = '13YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -155 Month))
        when return_period = '14YR_CUM' or return_period = '14YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -167 Month))
        when return_period = '15YR_CUM' or return_period = '15YR_ANN' then 
            last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL -179 Month))
        when return_period = 'SI_CUM' or return_period = 'SI_ANN' then 
            (select min(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id)
        END
        ,
        end_date=(select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id)
        ;
END
```

Comment: Why can't you make a database table that serves as a lookup for these values and use a `JOIN`? This is a huge mess of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is your repeating expression:

```
last_day(date_add((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id),INTERVAL {months} MONTH))
```

The only difference is the value in `{months}`.
First I would write the expression a bit shorter:

```
last_day((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id) + INTERVAL {months} MONTH)
```

Then I would use CASE only for the `{month}` part:

```
UPDATE period x
SET start_date = last_day((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id) + INTERVAL 
        CASE 
            when return_period = 'L3M' then -2
            when return_period = 'YTD' then -1
            when return_period = '1YR_CUM' or return_period = '1YR_ANN' then -11
            when return_period = '2YR_CUM' or return_period = '2YR_ANN' then -23
            when return_period = '3YR_CUM' or return_period = '3YR_ANN' then -35
            when return_period = '4YR_CUM' or return_period = '4YR_ANN' then -47
            # [...]
        END
    MONTH),
    end_date=(select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id);
```

You can also write it this way:

```
UPDATE period x
SET start_date = last_day((select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id) + INTERVAL 
        CASE return_period
            when 'L3M'     then -2
            when 'YTD'     then -1
            when '1YR_CUM' then -11
            when '1YR_ANN' then -11
            when '2YR_CUM' then -23
            when '2YR_ANN' then -23
            when '3YR_CUM' then -35
            when '3YR_ANN' then -35
            when '4YR_CUM' then -47
            when '4YR_ANN' then -47
            # [...]
        END
    MONTH),
    end_date=(select max(monthend_date) from returns y WHERE x.account_id=y.account_id);
```

Comment: Hi, this is my updated stored procedure.  Is there a way to reduce the repeating expression CASE 'SI_CUM' and 'SI_ANN'?